# view sql data into html

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to view some information from a SQL db inside an HTML page, but it doesn't work.
My code shows no results at all.

```
<?php 
    $host        = "DRHATEM-PC";          
    $user        = "sa";                 
    $pass        = "23635451";             
    $db          = "DR_HATEM_CLINIC";   
    @$connect = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server={".$host."}; Database={".$db."}", "".$user."", "".$pass."") or die("<center><b style=\"border:1px dashed #FF0000;\">".str_replace("[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]", "", odbc_errormsg())."</b></center>"); 
    $row = odbc_fetch_array(odbc_exec($connect, "select * from entrance"));
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <table style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f; border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;padding: 4px;background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.55);text-align:center;color: #fff;font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
            <tr> 
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.55);">ID</td> 
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.55);">Attend time</td> 
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.55);">Visit Reason</td> 
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.55);">Name</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['ID']; ?></td> 
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['date']; ?></td> 
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['vist_type']; ?></td>     
                <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['FullName']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: You're only displaying the first row of the results. If you want to display all the results, you need to call `odbc_fetch_array` in a loop.

Comment: *it doesn't work*... can you elaborate a little?

Comment: it don't show any results at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) do a loop for each row
2) echo the rows.  You only have `<?PHP $row['...']; ?>` which is nothing.

```
$qry = odbc_exec($connect, "select * from entrance");
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($qry)) {
... 
html with php:  echo $row['my key'];
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<?php $row['ID']; ?>` to `<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>` so the variable is printed out but you will still see only the first record. If there are more than one record you have to do like this:

```
<?php while($row = odbc_fetch_array(odbc_exec($connect, "select * from entrance")){ ?>
 <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['ID']; ?></td> 
    <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['date']; ?></td> 
    <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['vist_type']; ?></td>     
    <td style="border:1px solid #3f3f3f;"><?php $row['FullName']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope that this will help you